# Retrofit и XMPP

Tags: java, android, retrofit, xmpp

Я всегда использовала `Retrofit` вместе с `HTTP`, теперь стоит задача сделать месседжер, и всвязи с этим хочу спросить,  поддерживает ли `Retrofit` протокол `XMPP`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, Retrofit не поддерживает XMPP. Retrofit – это HTTP-клиент, предназначенный для работы с REST API.

Для работы с протоколом XMPP можете попробовать, например, [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/).

Comment: https://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ showing that Retrofit has support for XMPP protocol communication.